# Superimposing some plots with a txt file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

`I am trying to reproduce the attached figure step by step. My problem was that how can i plot colorbar in above figure by my data. My data is a cosmological data and it has 7 columns totally with many raw. My main goal is reproducing the present figure step by step. You can see that there are three different plots which are interpolated each other. Firstly, i tried to plot small colorful lines in the body of figure by using two columns of data. I did it by scatter plots and then i needed to reproduce the colorbar part of figure. But, it was not possible at the first attempt. Because, the colorbar points was not a part of data. Then, i obtained the values of colorbar by some calculations and added them as additional columns to data. Now, i could you the simple colorbar function to do colorbar part. And i got it. For the next step, i need to turn small curved lines to dark solid lines.

[image]

How can I do plots in matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.loadtxt("bei_predic.txt", unpack=True)
B = np.log10(data1[3]/(4.*(data1[2])))
R = np.vstack((data1,B))
R = np.transpose(R)
D = R[~np.isnan(R).any(axis=1)]


A = plt.scatter(D[:,3],D[:,2], c=D[:,8])
cbar= plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label("file", labelpad=+1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What data is in the columns, i.e. if you have (x, y, z) what does each represent? How would the data in z be represented in the plot? Do they only appear in the colorbar or do they have a correspondence in the plot (this second option seems the most likely). Try to include as many relevant details as possible (for example, what is the pink curve? Do you get it from your txt file? Is it in the same column as the black data points?).

Comment: Hi, Mehdi. Not everyone reads comments. It's better to edit your question trying to be as detailed as possible. This way, other people reading will have a better idea of what you need and can give more helpful answers. In particular, try to include the attempts you've made so far (you said you've managed to plot some of the data, add in your question the code you've used) and what exactly is that you can't do in the next step.

Comment: Hi. Again, please add all this (code and what you're trying to achieve) to the question, to make it more accessible to other people. As for the black plot, it might be a fit, or it might be a simulation, depending on what you're trying to do. In the first case, the data is used to generate the curves, using the fit functions in the `scipy` module for example; you'll need to know what function to use. If instead it's a simulation, the data have to agree with it but you can't use them to draw the curve. In this case you'll need to know the equation and the parameters you're simulating.

Comment: As it stands, the first sentence in your post is no longer related. As is the title. You should rephrase them both, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you could start off by telling us a little bit about the data that you are using that would be great. In order to plot the figure that you want, we must first load the data into some variables. Have you managed to do this?

Check out this example in which the author plots multicolored lines for some guidance.

Comment: Dear Thomas. I have an obtained list of data with 3 columns. two of them are as axis and i want to put the third as the vertical colorful part of the attached image.

Comment: Also, this is the output file and i should do some plots only with this txt file. If i had some other files of data, i could do this plot with Getdist. But this txt file is all i have.